# state hook in functional component (react 15.5.4)

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks, react-16

how I can manipulate state in functional component without using hook state? because it 's supported after 16.x version. I can't update current react version (it's very old and stability project). The problem is in the libraries used in the project, which use React.PropTypes instead just PropTypes :( thanks for your answers

Comment: There is no state in functional components.

Comment: Hooks are available only in 16.7 alpha currently and you cannot use state in functional components in any of the stable versions

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings ok. i understood you. sorry for stupid question. i can send more one argument and manipulate him from parent component)

Comment: @vlad_levii or just use a class component